# Ocaml - empty reference

Tags: reference, ocaml

How to create a empty reference? I mean something lika as

```
let x = ref Null
```

or

```
let x = ref None
```

or

```
let x = ref ()
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing in ML. A value of type `t ref` *always* holds a value of type `t`. This way, the curse of null pointer exceptions is avoided.

If you really need a nullable reference then you have to create a reference of type `t option ref`:

```
let r : int option ref = ref None
...
r := Some 5
```

The type system then ensures that you don't forget to handle the None case, e.g. with a match:

```
match !r with
| Some n -> ...
| None -> (* What now? *)
```

You should very rarely need such a thing, though. If you find yourself wanting an option ref then you should first try to restructure the problem.

Comment: type tree = Node of int * tree list  * tree ref
And now, I would like to create example tree. What should I do ?

Comment: Hard to say, this type definition does not really make a lot of sense to me. Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you're asking. There's nothing predefined named `Null` in OCaml. There is something named `None`, and indeed you can say `let x = ref None`. You can also say `let x = ref ()`. However it's hard to imagine a case where you'd want to do this. Since `()` is the only value of its type, you could never set `x` to any other value. So there would be no reason to use a reference.

Here is a session showing how to use `ref None`.

```
# let x = ref None;;
val x : '_a option ref = {contents = None}
# x := Some 5;;
- : unit = ()
# x;;
- : int option ref = {contents = Some 5}
# x := None;;
- : unit = ()
# x;;
- : int option ref = {contents = None}
```

Generally speaking an option type like `int option` allows you to have either an int value (like `Some 5`) or no value (`None`). Using a reference like `int option ref` gives you a mutable value that you can change between these two.

It looks to me like you're trying to reproduce patterns that you use in other languages. If possible you should try to learn OCaml in its own terms.